# Bootstrap navbar and isotope filtering

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, jquery-isotope

I am having troubles with Isotope on Navbar. I would like the content to be switched when selecting different Navbar items.

Not sure what do I have to do, this is simplified version of what I have for now.

I guess I need some Javascript that will handle the switching from navbar's href's to isotope's classes? Is this possible like this?

HTML Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse" id="#options">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

HTML Content

```
<section class="main-content">
  <div class="isotope-elements-grid" id="isotope-elements-grid">
    <div class="isotope-element home">
      <p>Some random text on Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="isotope-element about">
      <p>Some random text on About</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
$('.isotope-elements-grid').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.isotope-element',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
```